# how to chain sudo/su and still benefit from sudoers config

Tags: linux, sudo

I have two users that can `sudo` some commands without password (to simplify, lets assume they can run sudo ALL)

```
# /etc/sudoers
userA ALL = (root)   NOPASSWD: ALL
userB ALL = (root)   NOPASSWD: ALL
```

then I log in as my `userA` and want to debug a command run by userB.

```
userA@host$ sudo su userB
userB@host$ sudo whoami
[sudo] Password: <--- WHY?!
```

**From this point on I can't `sudo`. It will ask me for (possibly userB's) password.**

My first guess was that sudoers was differentiating between session and proper login session, but I still get the password prompt using `-s` with sudo and `-l` with su.

-- edit 1:

Also, just tested allowing sudo as ALL users and

```
userA@host$ sudo -s -u userB
userB@host$ sudo whoami
[sudo] Password: <--- WHY?!
```

but sudoers is still ignored and further sudo calls as userB shows the sudo password prompt just like before.

Comment: `su` is to switch user, and `sudo` is to run a command as another user.  There is no real purpose to combining them.  I'm not sure what you're trying to solve; why not just open another terminal?

Comment: @Wildcard i am userA. i do not know userB passwords.  that's why i sudo/su as it. i combine two because i use `sudo` to run command as root, who can then `su` as userB. i tried to simplify that after my edit1. where i allow userA to impersonate userB directly. that is a little easier to follow up and show the issue as well.

Comment: also, note `sudo -s` will start a shell. while it is technically "running a command" the practical consequence is very similar to "switching user"/

Comment: Right, but if you already used `sudo -s` to start a shell as userB, then you can run commands as userB just by typing them; you don't need to use `sudo` anymore.  `sudo` without the `-u` flag just runs a command as root, so there's no reason to switch to userB if you're just going to run a command as root anyway.

Comment: To put it more simply: Just run `sudo su userB` followed by `whoami`, NOT `sudo whoami`.

Comment: @Wildcard the whole problem is that i want to test a process that do require `sudo x` as userB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29995/discussion-between-wildcard-and-gcb).